# Reinstall ms office 2013 without product key (bought through HUP)

Tags: microsoft-office, reinstall

I got virus on my computer and need to reinstall everything including MS office 2013. The problem is that I do not remember product key and I bought it through my former employer (HUP).

Is it still possible to reinstall MS office 2013?

Comment: You won't be able to activate Office 2013, which means while you might be able to install it, you won't actually be able to use it.  Office cannot be used unless it's activated.

Comment: @Ramhound Is there way to extract product key from my current installation?

Comment: If the system is still bootable you can use this utility to find the key.....https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

Comment: @Moab Thank you, system is still usable, I am slowly preparing for reinstall. I ordered new disk to dump everything on it and then reinstall.

Comment: If you purchased Office through HUP, you can enter the work email address that you used to buy Office to sign in www.microsoft.com/home-use-program/order-history. This will send an email to yourself that contains a list of all products you purchased on www.microsofthup.com, along with their product keys. For details, refer to: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-help-installing-office-through-microsoft-hup-f682c420-ed43-42d9-96e4-235dd7708848?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_hupinstalllink